# How to cache data during application startup in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I have a Spring boot Application connecting to SQL Server Database. I need some help in using caching in my application. I have a table for CodeCategory which has a list of codes for Many codes. This table will be loaded every month and data changes only once in a month. 
I want to cache this entire table when the Application starts. In any subsequent calls to the table should get value from this cache instead of calling the Database.

For Example,

```
List<CodeCategory> findAll();
```

I want to cache the above DB query value during application startup.  If there is a DB call like `List<CodeCategory> findByCodeValue(String code)` should fetch the code result from the already Cached data instead of calling the Database.

Please let me know how this can be achieved using spring boot and ehcache.

Comment: I believe you already have spring cache abstraction and ehcache implementation in place with appropriate caching annotations. Just invoke get call in ```@PostConstruct``` method this will ensure to populate the cache during the application startup

Comment: @Barath This will cache the entire table data. Will the queries to get partial data from table (like value for a Particular code) will refer to this cache?

Comment: @Barath : Can you please provide a link where I can refer to the code you have mentioned.

Comment: Here is a link to the reference [ehcache](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-caching-workshop/blob/master/spring-caching-ehcache-demo/src/main/java/com/barath/app/Application.java)

Comment: This won't work. It will cache results for the method call. It won't populate a cache for individual retrieval. instead use the proper 2nd level cache of your JPA provider (hibernate I suspect) to handle this.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Yes I am using ehcache with my application. Can you please share some code sample or link to achieve the functionality mentioned.

Comment: Second level caching is explained in the reference guide of your persistence framework. Probably hibernate in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, It takes some time for ehcache to setup and it is not working completely with `@PostConstruct`. In that case make use of `ApplicationStartedEvent` to load the cache.

GitHub Repo: [spring-ehcache-demo](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-caching-workshop/blob/master/spring-caching-ehcache-demo/src/main/java/com/barath/app/Application.java)

```java
@Service
class CodeCategoryService{

   @EventListener(classes = ApplicationStartedEvent.class )
   public void listenToStart(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        this.repo.findByCodeValue("100");
   }

}

interface CodeCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<CodeCategory, Long>{

    @Cacheable(value = "codeValues")
    List<CodeCategory> findByCodeValue(String code);
}
```

**Note:** There are multiple ways as pointed by others. You can choose as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

My way is to define a generic cache handler

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GenericCacheHandler {

List<CodeCategory> findAll();
 }
```

And its implementation as below

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling  // Important
public class GenericCacheHandlerImpl implements GenericCacheHandler {

@Autowired
private CodeRepository codeRepo;

private List<CodeCategory> codes = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
private void intializeBudgetState() {
    List<CodeCategory> codeList = codeRepo.findAll();
    // Any customization goes here
    codes = codeList;
}

@Override
public List<CodeCategory> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}
}
```

Call it in **Service** layer as below

```
@Service
public class CodeServiceImpl implements CodeService {

@Autowired
private GenericCacheHandler genericCacheHandler;

@Override
public CodeDTO anyMethod() {
    return genericCacheHandler.getCodes();
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second level hibernate caching to cache all the required db queries.

For caching at the application start-up, we can use @PostContruct in any of the Service class.

Syntax will be :-

```
@Service
public class anyService{

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
     //call any method
 }
}
```

Comment: This will cache the entire table data. Will the queries to get partial data from table (like value for a Particular code) will refer to this cache?

Comment: No, if you want to use query caching please use ehCache for it

Answer (score 0):

Use **CommandLineRunner** interface. 
Basically , you can create a Spring @Component and implement CommandLineRunner interface. You will have to override it's run method. The run method will be called at the start of the app.

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements 
CommandLineRunner {

   @override
   Public void run(.... string){
     // Any code here gets called at the start of the app.
  }}
```

This approach is mostly used to bootstrap the application with some initial data.

Answer (score 0):

Service -

```
    @Service
    public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "product", key = "#id")
    public ProductDto findById(Long id) {
        Product savedProduct = productRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found"));
        ProductDto productDto = new ProductDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(savedProduct, productDto);
        return productDto;
    }

}
```

Commandline runner implementation -

```
    @Component
    public class InitialDataLoad implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        productService.findById(1L);
    }

}
```