# How to load a table at the beginning of the program in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is a table named "Employees" which has employeeName and employeeId. I want to load it into a HashMap<string,string> as soon as the program starts, so that other functions can access it. I am using springboot. I have following files right now,

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }
}
```

IEmployeeRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface IEmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository {

    @Query(value = "select * from Employee")
    HashMap<String ,String> EmployeeReferenceTable();
}
```

IEmployeeRepository will give the HashMap. I have another file called EmployeeTable.java, which should call the Repository and get the whole table.

EmployeeTable.java

```
public class rdEmployee {


    @Bean
    public HashMap<String, String> EmployeeHashMap(){
        // Should get the HashMap from Repository file.

    }

}
```

Other then these there are files which needs the above Employee Table values. How to do it? Am I even doing it correctly? Bean annotation is used so that it is done at the beginning of the program. Is it used correctly? IEmployeeRepository is an interface, so how to call it from EmployeeHashMap()?

Comment: `@Component public class rdLanguage {`

Comment: Why not simply enable query caching for this particular query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add @Component annotation of field of Class then use @Bean annotations then implement your logic there

```
@Component  
 public class rdEmployee {


    @Bean
    public HashMap<String, String> EmployeeHashMap(){
        // Should get the HashMap from Repository file.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these annotations for your entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_table")
public class Employee{ // attributes}
```

So repository goes:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Also as soon as the program starts these are available, so it is that you should write a service and then make sure it is called before any other rest calls or service calls get called.

Comment: Can I call it in the Application.java file?

Comment: Won't adding @Bean/@component execute them before anything else internally?

Comment: @SudoPehpeh I think you are looking more something like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471247/how-to-cache-data-during-application-startup-in-spring-boot-application , check his question if it is the one